# IntelliJ not seeing resources folder

Tags: properties, maven-2, intellij-idea, file-not-found

I created a new Project from scratch in IntelliJ by using a `Maven Module`. I didn't select any specific archetypes and I clicked on finish. The project gets created nicely and I have the `java` and `resources` folders under src/main as expected.

Unfortunately, my application does not find any property files in the `resources` folder because it looks in the project base folder instead.

I double checked that the resources folder is marked as 'source folder' in the Project Structure and I also tried to add the following to the pom.xml with no success:

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

I'm using Maven 2.2.1 and IntelliJ 11.1, Any thoughts??

Comment: IDEA community edition 11.1.2 works well. Custom resource dirs not seem, but default dir 'src/main/resources' see well

Comment: See http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Maven_FAQ.

Comment: What kind of resources do you have there? If it something custom types (*.bin, etc) you have to specify compiler to include these files

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot or typed text-version of your project's directory structure?

Comment: One other thing to try... IDEA project creation sucks, unfortunately. I always use `mvn` command line with `archetype:generate` to create new projects. Then I use the POM file as a way to create a new IDEA project with existing sources (I think). If you have a pom, try deleting all your IDEA project files (.ipr, .iml, .idea, etc) and then creating a new IDEA project using the POM file. See what happens...

Answer (score 9):

There is a bug in Intellij 12 please go to Settings->Compiler and un-check "Use external build" check box - the idea behind it was that it was suppose to run faster with a compiler run in a separate process but in fact there is a bug and when using maven it does not copy resources.

Comment: Link to a relevant entry in IntelliJ issue tracker mentioning the fix: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-97759

Comment: For those using IntelliJ IDEA 13, external build is the only option available since the older compiler has been removed. Thus, you won't find any checkbox for "Use external build".

Answer (score 7):

Right Click the Directory -> "Mark Directory as" -> "Resource Root"

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and resolved it.
My issue was not an Intellij issue, it was an error in my pom.xml
I had included this by mistake:

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

Removing this (or correcting it) fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

or under settings -> compiler -> resource patterns, add the resource pattern (i.e ?*.prefs)

Answer (score 1):

Had similar issue. Solution that worked for me:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("path").getFile());
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the answer is quite simple ..!
Just reference the file path in your source code as below:

`src\\main\\resources\\FileName`

& it should work as expected.